# Structuring a list of components that have to remove themselves in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm not sure if this belongs on SO because it's more about design than programming.

I have an array of models and each model has a corresponding component. The components can delete their models. However, when the model is deleted, they should also be removed from the array.

Here are 2 ways I'm approaching this problem:

```
{{#each item in items}}
  {{item-row item=item items=items}}
{{/each}}
```

In this case, I'm passing the entire array to the child component. The child component can remove its own item from the items array.

Here's the second way:

```
{{#each item in items}}
  {{item-row item=item removeItem="removeItem"}}
{{/each}}
```

Here, the child component sends a `removeItem` action. When the parent component receives the `removeItem` action, it removes the item from the array.

Which is the better way to do this in Ember? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend the second way, using a removeItem action on the component. It's much cleaner, and your item-row component has no need to know about the other items, so why should it? Plus that means it doesn't update every time `items` is changed, so slightly more efficient.

The best way to go about this would be to pass that component's item when calling `removeItem`.

`this.sendAction('removeItem', this.get('item'));`

Then you just handle removing the item from the array in the `removeItem` action on the controller.

```
removeItem: function(removedItem) {
  // As items is an array, iterate through it and remove the removedItem
  var updatedItems = this.get('items').filter(function(item) {
    return item.get('id') !== removedItem.get('id');
  });
  this.set('items', updatedItems);
}
```

Hope that helps!